# Modifying program's drive path after installation?

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-2

I had installed Sublime text on drive `D:`. After few days of working with it, I would like to have the program hosted on the `E:` drive, *without* going through the uninstall-install cycle.

Is it possible? I have some files saved inside that editor, so after hosting in `E:` drive, will it be the same again?

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short: You Can't.

User folder, such as Documents, Pictures, Music, Downloads, etc are easily movable. If you want the programs moved to another location, uninstall them first, then re-install, specifying a different target location.